# Internal server error during video file upload in php codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, video, file-upload

Same function is working on local but not on server.

This is my Controller code:

```
public function upload_video() {
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('userid');
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/video/' . $user_id . '/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'mp4|flv|wmv';
    $config['encrypt_name'] = true;
    $config['max_size'] = '60240000';

    if (!file_exists($config['upload_path'])) {
        mkdir($config['upload_path']);
    }

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()):

        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        print_r($error);
    else:

        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $filename = $data['file_name'];
       echo trim($data['file_name'] = $filename);

    endif;

}
```

Comment: did you set the proper permission on your server for the upload folder?

Comment: the function is working fine on server with the video file size less than 10 MB, error occurs only when i am trying to upload file size more than 10 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if (!$this->upload->do_upload()):` should be `if (!$this->upload->do_upload('user_file')):`

Where `user_file` is your file input field's `name` attribute's value.
 In this case your view file should contain following input

```
<input type="file" name="user_file"/>
```

Comment: it could be you direction creation issue `$test = mkdir($config['upload_path']);var_dump($test)` test it whether it returns TRUE

Answer (score 0):

configure your server to accept large file size

Set your `upload_max_filesize` & `post_max_size` to a larger number